# Azure IoT Hub Databricks Exception

Tags: scala, azure, databricks, azure-iot-hub

I am running a scala notebook to process Azure IoT Hub telemetry data. The book runs fine for a few minutes and suddenly throws this below exception. I have a separate consumer group for reading the events but still facing the issue. I tried to check the open issues under github and it seems like the issue has been reported earlier - https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/issues/462. Any suggestions or work around how I can handle this?

The configuration I am using:

Databricks Version: 6.3 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.4, Scala 2.11)

com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.3.13

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: In partition 3 of xxxxx, with consumer group delta, request seqNo 90273 is less than the received seqNo 90274. The earliest seqNo is 16302 and the last seqNo is 90322
at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.CachedEventHubsReceiver.checkCursor(CachedEventHubsReceiver.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.CachedEventHubsReceiver.org$apache$spark$eventhubs$client$CachedEventHubsReceiver$$receive(CachedEventHubsReceiver.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.CachedEventHubsReceiver$.receive(CachedEventHubsReceiver.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.rdd.EventHubsRDD.compute(EventHubsRDD.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:533)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1541)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:539)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2362)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2350)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2349)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2349)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2581)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2529)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2517)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:897)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.runSparkJobs(Collector.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.collect(Collector.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollectResult(limit.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectResult(Dataset.scala:2890)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2857)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2857)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$54.apply(Dataset.scala:3492)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$54.apply(Dataset.scala:3487)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withAction(Dataset.scala:3487)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2857)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MemorySink.addBatch(memory.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:566)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:208)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: In partition 3 of b2bhub, with consumer group delta, request seqNo 90273 is less than the received seqNo 90274. The earliest seqNo is 16302 and the last seqNo is 90322
    at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.CachedEventHubsReceiver.checkCursor(CachedEventHubsReceiver.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.CachedEventHubsReceiver.org$apache$spark$eventhubs$client$CachedEventHubsReceiver$$receive(CachedEventHubsReceiver.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.client.CachedEventHubsReceiver$.receive(CachedEventHubsReceiver.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.eventhubs.rdd.EventHubsRDD.compute(EventHubsRDD.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:533)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1541)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:539)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```